# How to cast a parent class to its child class in Dart

Tags: class, flutter, dart, casting, extends

I have two classes A and B extend A.

```
class A{
  String a;
  A();
}
class B extends A{
  String b;
  B();
}
```

How to getA Like:

```
B getA(){
  return A();
}
```

Or

```
  B b = A();
```

My Code :

```
  Future<B> getB() async {
    return apiMethod("url", headers: {'requirestoken': true}, httpEnum: HttpEnum.GET).then((response) {
      return B.fromJson(response.data);
    }).catchError((error, stacktrace) => A.catchErrorMethod(error, stacktrace));
  }
```

**While class A**

```
class A {
  A.catchErrorMethod(error, stacktrace):....
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what the idea here is behind the A class

Comment: [super?](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#extending-a-class)

Answer (score 6):

I had a same problem to "casting". The Dart solution is use "as" like this:

```
B b = A() as B;
```

[Dart: Docs: Fixing common type problems](https://dart.dev/guides/language/sound-problems#invalid-casts)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do this.
B is an A but A is not a B.

However you can simply use B everywhere as if it was an A

Comment: Thanks, I need a way to do that?

Comment: Could you then add a more concrete version of what you want to do (so the concept and maybe some actual code).